# Strange Vagrant / SSH Connection Behaviour

Tags: ssh, connection, capistrano, chef-infra, vagrant

I'm running some Capistrano & Chef tasks on some local vagrant VM's. I can SSH into these boxes normally from the command line.

When I try to run some Capistrano tasks, I will always get the following error the *first* time I run the Cap task:

```
connection failed for: 192.168.0.220 (Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer)
```

It will occasionally fail a second time too.  But then when I run it again, it works!  This behaviour makes no sense to me and I haven't the slightest idea how to troubleshoot.

Any help you could provide would be appreciated!

Comment: I also have same issue starting a few days ago with deployhq. All works fine when running same commands when I login manually, but such command will fail - `COMMAND="sleep 3000" cap invoke`. Very strange issue.

Comment: I have also seen this behaviour when calling commands from other language environments such as in gradle, pyinvoke, and rake. I've never been able to find the solution. It's happening now with calling ansible from pyinvoke.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue before, The Problem is faced was the machine didn't have enough resources to execute tasks.

I increased ram to the machine, everything started working again.